# Installation/Configuration Error Installing 2012 SSRS Native Mode

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2012

I believe I properly installed Reporting Services for SQL Server 2012 Developer edition however I get a HTTP 500 error when attempting to view the report viewer or manager URLs in both IE 10 and Firefox (with administrator privileges) on the same dev machine.  Sometimes a login prompt is displayed, which I have tried entering the service account credentials in but this also results in the 500 HTTP error. Using the default options, the report services install reported running successfully on my Windows 8.1 dev machine.  Since this feature was added to a MSSQL instance with the name SQLEXPRESS the Web Service and Report Manager URLs were configured as ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS and Reports_SQLEXPRESS which per the MSDN installation directions is correct.  Port 80 is open on my dev server and is not currently being utilized by an IIS site.  I also attempted to apply URLs for port 86 which is also available.  I can access IIS sites (locally) on my dev box on port 80 and 86 so I do not believe the Window Firewall or any other firewall is blocking access.  I even tried setting the virtual directory URL for the Reports Manager to "Reports_SQLEXPRESS_0" since the error below reference that as the instance name but that also did not work.  All standard MSSQL 2012 server service updates have been applied to the server.  I am also running .net 4.0 and 4.5 on the same dev server.  The ReportServerService log file keeps reporting the following error which I believe is related to this but I do not know what should be done to correct the error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> ERROR: 
>   Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerAppDomainManagerException:
>   Failed to create Report Server HTTP Runtime,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerAppDomainManagerException:
>   An error occurred when attempting to start the application domain
>   ReportServer within the Report Server service. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException:
>   An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for
>   application domain ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS_0.  --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:  path
>   attribute must be a relative virtual path.  It cannot contain any of
>   '?' ':' '\' '*' '"' '<' '>' or '|'.
>   (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config
>   line 12)

Comment: What is on line 12 of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nic, for pointing me in the direction of what should have been obvious. I guess the way the error message read I didn't think the configuration of the .net services would be the issue though it was.  By commenting out line 12 of the .net web.config which is shown below, it appears the issue has been resolved.  I think this was applied previously to troubleshoot an issue on a different site and was no longer needed.  It appears this configuration was causing the report server web service to attempt to redirect to :85 causing the failure.  Note, where localhost_ip is stated that was the actual ip of the server but removed for this forum post.

```
    <!--<location path="localhost_ip:85" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
        <securityPolicy>
            <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
            <trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config"/>
            <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config"/>
            <trustLevel name="Low" policyFile="web_lowtrust.config"/>
            <trustLevel name="Minimal" policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config"/>
        </securityPolicy>
        <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
    </system.web>
</location>-->
```