# SS Reporting Services Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I am getting below issues while accessing SSRS.
Can anyone let me know if you have faced this issue before.

> The RSReportServer.config file has been modified.
>
> Report ServerWindows Service (MSSQLSERVER) cannot connect to the report server
>   database. The value for UrlRoot in RSReportServer.config is not valid.
>   The default value will be used instead.

---

> library!DefaultDomain!2b94!12/02/2016-19:48:43:: w WARN: Initializing
>   UrlRoot to default value of ''  because it was incorrectly specified
>   in Configuration file as ''.

---

> INFO: Registered url=http://+:81/Reports/, vdir=/Reports,
>   pdir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager.

---

> library!DefaultDomain!4c0!12/01/2016-18:35:35:: e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   The report server cannot open a connection to the report server
>   database. A connection to the database is required for all requests
>   and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open
>   database "ReportServer" requested by the login. The login failed.

I clicked the "test connection" button in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager and it succeeds.

Comment: it says `Cannot open database "ReportServer" requested by the login.` do you have proper connectivity and login can access the database.

Comment: Yes @Kin,I have proper access to service account used by ssrs.DBowner and RSexec role.

Comment: The error is fairly clear, you have an incorrect database, and an incorrect urlroot. Could you open Reporting services Configuration manager and fix your settings using the GUI (there is a test button I believeà

Comment: Looks like your `RSReportServer.config` is corrupt or has been changed.

Comment: Is this ok or should I change http://+:81/Reports/.Please let me know if I Re-Install issue might fix.

Comment: +:81/Reports is probably the issue. Check out http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156677/installation-configuration-error-installing-2012-ssrs-native-mode from earlier this week

Comment: Were you creating a standalone SSRS instance on a different server than your actual SQL Server?  Did you create the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases from the Report Service Configuration Manager?